# SQL Loader Error while loading the data from xml file to table

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to load the data from an xml file to a table. I get the below errors, please help me out.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_XML
(FILL CHAR(30)
XMLDATA CLOB);
```

**Here is my control file**

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE * 
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE TEST_XML XMLType(XMLDATA)
FIELDS ( FILL FILLER CHAR(100), XMLDATA LOBFILE(CONSTANT test_file.xml) TERMINATED BY EOF ) 
BEGINDATA 0
```

**I get the below error:**

> Table `TEST_XML`, loaded from every logical record. Insert option in
>   effect for this table: TRUNCATE
>
> Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
>   ------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- --------------------- FILL                                FIRST   100           CHARACTER               (FILLER FIELD) XMLDATA
>   DERIVED     *  EOF      CHARACTER
>       Static LOBFILE.  Filename is test_file.xml
>
> Record 1: Rejected - Error on table TEST_XML. ORA-01008: not all
>   variables bound

Answer (score 0):

For me it is invalid syntax in control file. Oder of key word is relevant. Also like  after `begindata`

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE * 
INTO TABLE TEST_XML
truncate
FIELDS
 ( FILL FILLER CHAR(100)
  ,XMLDATA LOBFILE(CONSTANT test_file.xml) TERMINATED BY EOF ) 
BEGINDATA 
0
```